# Create new row in existing table from textfield input. SwiftUI (storyboards )

Tags: swift, tableview, swiftui, textfield, populate

I am looking for a basic example of getting textField values from swiftUI (form input) and inserting these values as a new row in an already existing table

the form is a basic add record form. 4 fields. data type not important right now.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An example of that will be

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var tableData = ["one", "two", "tree"]

    @State var newData = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack{
            TextField("Enter Data", text: $newData)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding(.top,20)
            Button("Submit")
            {
                self.tableData.insert(self.newData, at: 0)
            }
            List(tableData, id:\.self){element in
                Text(element)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example NoodleOfDeath. my view.controller file shows "import cocoa" instead of swift UI. would this be an issue?

Comment: You need to choose User Interface - Swiftui, when creating and naming your new project. Here is how create new swiftui project https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views .  You have chosen storyboard, that is why you see a Viewcontroller file. If you choose swiftui, you will see ContentView.swift file in you new project, it i where this code must be.